# Getting a citation on the same line as an equation, in theorem environment

Tags: equations, citing, theorems

Just wondered if anyone could help me with this issue. I'm trying to reference a theorem using \cite{ref}, but the theorem finishes with an equation, so the citation move onto the next line. This is the code I have:

```
\begin{thm}[Euler's Formula]
Let $G$ be any planar graph which contains $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces of $G$. Then,
$$v-e+f=2.$$
\cite{ref}
\end{thm}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you're using `amsmath`, you could try this: `\[ v-e+f=2. \qquad \text{\cite{ref}} \]`

Comment: Are you trying to create a cross-reference to a theorem that's been set up elsewhere in the document? If that's the case, you should use `\ref{ref}` rather than `\cite{ref}`.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `amsmath`, you could try this:

```
\[
 v-e+f=2. \qquad \text{\cite{ref}}
\]
```

an additional comment on the style ...

it would be beneficial for you to become more familiar with "good practices".  here are a couple of questions that address that topic.

[Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

[What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)

Comment: It seems `\text` isn't even necessary. This is one more example why one should not use `$$ … $$`, b.t.w.